# How can I get this partial view to render correctly?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have the following code in an MVC 3 view

```
    <% foreach (var stockItem in Model.Shop.Stock) { %>
        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("ItemImageDisplay", stockItem.Item); %>
            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong><%= stockItem.Item.ToString() %></strong><br />
                <%= stockItem.Item.CalculatePrice() %><br />
                <%= stockItem.Quantity %> in stock<br />
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Buy", "BuyShopItem", new { shopId = Model.Shop.Id, itemId = stockItem.Item.Id }, null) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
```

When this is rendered, the "ItemImageDisplay" partial view is not inside the div tag that I have placed it in, it instead renders as if I had put:

```
    <% foreach (var stockItem in Model.Shop.Stock) { %>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("ItemImageDisplay", stockItem.Item); %>
    <% } %>

    <% foreach (var stockItem in Model.Shop.Stock) { %>
        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong><%= stockItem.Item.ToString() %></strong><br />
                <%= stockItem.Item.CalculatePrice() %><br />
                <%= stockItem.Quantity %> in stock<br />
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Buy", "BuyShopItem", new { shopId = Model.Shop.Id, itemId = stockItem.Item.Id }, null) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
```

The html of the partial view is as follows:

```
<%= Html.Image("~/Content/Images/Items/" + Model.Id + ".png", Model.ToString(), new { onmouseover = "tooltip('item:" + Model.Id + "');", onmousemove = "tooltip('item:" + Model.Id + "');", onmouseout = "tooltipRem();" }) %>
```

Please can you help me to understand why this is rendering as it is and what I can do to stop this from happening?

EDIT: Here is the rendered output for this section:

```
<img alt="Can of Pineapples" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:1152&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:1152&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/1152.png" title="Can of Pineapples" /><img alt="Kraken Treats" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:1104&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:1104&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/1104.png" title="Kraken Treats" /><img alt="Orange Jelly" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:1279&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:1279&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/1279.png" title="Orange Jelly" /><img alt="Peanuts" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:509&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:509&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/509.png" title="Peanuts" /><img alt="Fourth Year Anaversary Cake" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:859&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:859&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/859.png" title="Fourth Year Anaversary Cake" /><img alt="Taco" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:486&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:486&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/486.png" title="Taco" /><img alt="Can of Blueberries" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:1154&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:1154&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/1154.png" title="Can of Blueberries" /><img alt="Strawberry Jam" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:639&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:639&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/639.png" title="Strawberry Jam" /><img alt="Crisps" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:726&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:726&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/726.png" title="Crisps" /><img alt="Cooked Shrimp" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:521&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:521&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/521.png" title="Cooked Shrimp" /><img alt="Fishy Finger" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:629&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:629&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/629.png" title="Fishy Finger" /><img alt="Can of Peaches" onmousemove="tooltip(&#39;item:1151&#39;);" onmouseout="tooltipRem();" onmouseover="tooltip(&#39;item:1151&#39;);" src="/Content/Images/Items/1151.png" title="Can of Peaches" />

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Can of Pineapples</strong><br />
                940<br />
                10 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=1152">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Kraken Treats</strong><br />
                934<br />
                7 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=1104">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Orange Jelly</strong><br />
                827<br />
                9 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=1279">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Peanuts</strong><br />
                116<br />
                8 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=509">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Fourth Year Anaversary Cake</strong><br />
                1794<br />
                7 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=859">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Taco</strong><br />
                950<br />
                7 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=486">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Can of Blueberries</strong><br />
                317<br />
                8 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=1154">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Strawberry Jam</strong><br />
                1032<br />
                10 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=639">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Crisps</strong><br />
                179<br />
                10 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=726">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Cooked Shrimp</strong><br />
                663<br />
                11 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=521">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Fishy Finger</strong><br />
                974<br />
                10 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=629">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shopItem">
            <div class="shopItemLeft">

            </div>
            <div class="shopItemRight">
                <strong>Can of Peaches</strong><br />
                786<br />
                7 in stock<br />
                <a href="/Market/BuyShopItem?shopId=1&amp;itemId=1151">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the html output from the rendered view/partial view?

Comment: Sorry, should have thought to add that. I have edited the question

Comment: Is that the actual source of the page or the page as inspected with a dom browser like firebug or ie developer tools.  Javascript can change the dom but not the page source. Ther is nothing wrong with the code you've posted as far as i can tell, it should output as you expect.

Comment: The rendered HTML I have posted is a copy and paste from view source in IE. it looks the same in Google Chrome.

If I put the html from the partial view where the call to the partialview is in the view, then it outputs as expected. Unfortunately, that would mean I would have to do that same line many times across my website and would not be easy for me to change in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm i suspect it is because you are using `Html.RederPartial` rather than `Html.Partial`.  The latter returns a string whereas the former writes directly to the response stream.  I have a sneaky feeling that MVC is executing the entire foreach loop and then writing to the response at the end which would explain your results.